# Return first matched folder in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an array of IDs that have corresponding directories in a share:

```
$ids = @('12345','25356','74678')
```

```
- C:
-- 2020
--- 12345678 SURNAME
---- 12345
----- 12345_SubDir01
----- 12345_SubDir[n]
--- 23648844 SURNAME
---- 25256
----- 25256_SubDir01
----- 25256_SubDir[n]
```

I want to loop through all the directories in the letter `C:` and find the first match (the ID not the ID with the sub directory). So I want to match on `12345` not `12345_SubDir01`.

The line that I've found so far (though inefficient) works but then keeps searching until it has iterated every directory in the the root share (we have over 500,000 folders and sub-folders).

The script line I am working with:

```
Get-ChildItem C: -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "12345" }
```

Is there a way to get the script to stop once it has matched on the ID so it doesn't continue searching once it has found the directory?

I want to be able to use the output path in the second half of the script, but its taking about 20 minutes per ID match before it can pass it on..

Comment: If you add ‘ | Select-Object -First 1’ to the end it should stop after finding the first

Comment: @DougMaurer worked a charm! i didnt know about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits go to [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) for `| Select-Object -First 1`. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) could be clearer about the fact that the **pipeline will actually exit** as soon as the specified number of input objects have been received (in our case, when the first matching name has been found).

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object -Property Name -eq 12345 | Select-Object -First 1
```

Further improvements:

- In this simple case, we can make everything more concise by using only parameters instead of a script block for `Where-Object`.

  `Get-ChildItem -Directory` limits retrieval to directories. Analogously, there's `-File`. Note that these require **PS v3+**.
  For older PS versions, one can query `$_.PSIsContainer` as shown in the question.
- Make sure to append a backslash to `C:`. If you pass the drive without backslash, you will search only in the *current directory* of the drive! Try it: `cd c:\windows; Get-ChildItem C:`. You will list the content of the "windows" directory. The backslash fixes that, as you now specify the root directory, not just the drive.
- Use operator `-eq` for an exact (case insensitive) match. With operator `-match` you would get an unwanted match for `12345_SubDir01`, because `-match` does a sub-string search by default.

Comment: Nicely done! I was going to add similar details when I had time if no one else had.